# MySQL PHP incompatibility SQLSTATE[HY000] [2054] The server requested authentication method umknown to the client

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, pdo, compatibility

I was trying to set up a mysql connection with php using PDO.

Here are the version of the software I use :

- windows 7 64
- mysql 8.0.18
- php 7.3.11

I tried to execute the connection command line into the PHP code :

```
try {
    $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test_php', $user, $pass);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    phpinfo();
    exit('Erreur : ' . $e->getMessage());
}
```

The php server shows this error message while executing the code above :

> Erreur : SQLSTATE[HY000] [2054] The server requested authentication method unknown to the client

I've double check the $user and $password into mysql, also create new mysql account to make sure I haven't made a mistake.

Here is a sample of my php.ini file where I activated the pdo driver (and also fix the problem with the location of the "ext" folder in Windows)

```
extension=pdo_mysql
extension_dir = "C:\BAK\php_7.3.11\ext"
```

Does anybody know what i've done wrong ?

Comment: There is no code to support the question/tags used.

Comment: Oh, I see what this is about. That isn't how things work here on Stack. You need to post code and then post the solution for you. This however, should also help others who might have experienced the same problem. Otherwise, it will be too localized.

Comment: It took me a long time to figure out what was happening. This is the solution i've found : :

- when you create the database user, use a mysql_native_password type for your password

`CREATE USER 'your_user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED  WITH mysql_native_password BY 'your_password';`

mysql_native_password is the old authentification method to use instead of the new one who cause the error.

Comment: I've correct my question and hope it is clear enough. I've put the answer in comment to avoid losing it because I can't find any "solution" button (probably because the question is "closed").

Answer (score 1):

It took me a long time to figure out what was happening. This is the solution i've found

When you create the database user, use a mysql_native_password type for your password :

```
CREATE USER 'your_user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'your_password';
```

mysql_native_password is the old authentification method to use instead of the new one who cause the error.
This ways, the authentication protocol between the PHP server and the mysql database is understood by both.